# Mocking a function call inside a constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have built a file manager(basically reads/writes) class I am trying to unit test. The file format basically belongs to a third party for which I have third party function calls in the constructor. I call all third party calls through wrapper methods
My question is this: Before starting to unit test any method in the class I am trying to instantiate the constructor which looks something like this:

```
Filemanager::Filemanager{

if(wrapperfoo()){
   file->open() //for writing
}

initialise();
}
```

Now I have a mock class MockManager to mock Filemanager. When I am trying to instantiate MockManager,
I need to mock wrapperoo to return true. However, since the manager itself is not instantiated yet, the EXPECT_CALL fails. Since the EXPECT_CALL has to be placed before the new MockManager()

```
MockManager *mgr;
EXPECT_CALL(*mgr, wrapperfoo()).Return(true) // Crashes here.. Obviously!!
mgr = new MockManager();
```

How can I handle this case?

Comment: move `file->open` inside `initialise` then call `initialise` outside the constructor

Comment: Why do you have logic *in your mock*? Mock shouldn't do anything by itself. It only informs you that it has been used and it returns values that you requested to return. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I see no chance for this to work, you are forced to build yourself a workaround. You already gave the explanation yourself.

In principle, mocking isn't designed for what you want to achieve, it is designed for testing components in their behavior to an API or interface, where you mock the interface (API) for the component and not vice versa (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLB2aDasVTg&list=PL_dsdStdDXbo-zApdWB5XiF2aWpsqzV55&index=4, very good explanation). In this example you wouldn't use mocking for internal calls (from the contructor), rather in the test case of another component that requests to get the return type from `wrapperfoo()`.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer itself, i would have made it a comment but I'm lacking the reputation, sorry for any inconvenience